# NGINX Serve static files inside a nested location

Tags: nginx

I have a nested location directive, I want to serve the app at the `/api` and the static files in the `/api/static/`

For serving static files I'm using `try_files $uri /dev/null =404` inside a nested location.

```
location /api/ {

        location /api/static/ {
            try_files $uri /dev/null =404;
            root /shared_volumes/staticfiles/;
        }

        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
        proxy_pass              http://app:8000/api/;
    }
```

but that doesn't work, nginx returns not found when accesing `http://app/api/static/afile.css` although the file exists in `/shared_volumes/static/afile.css`

In the NGINX docs $uri is

> current URI in request, normalized The value of $uri may change during
>   request processing, e.g. when doing internal redirects, or when using
>   index files.

How does nginx $uri behave in nested location?
Does nginx search file `api/static/afile.css` in `/shared_volumes/staticfiles/` instead of `afile.css`?

Comment: The URI `/api/static/afile.css` will be looked for at `/shared_volumes/staticfiles/api/static/afile.css`. That's how [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) works. Perhaps you need to use [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) instead.

Comment: BTW, this `try_files` is meaningless. Even more, it will try file `$root/dev/null`, I doubt you've meant that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `/api/static/` location directive as sugested by @Richard and @Alexey in the comment above

```
    location /api/static/ {
        alias /shared_volumes/staticfiles/;
    }
```

and it now works, thanks!